# How do you delete all PartOrder records for Orders for which the shipping date is in the past?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you delete all PartOrder records for Orders for which the shipping date is in the past? I am currently working with an oracle database sql64plus.

Some background knowledge:
pooid is the Foreign key in the Table PartOrder connected to oid which is the primary key in the Table Orders
So far i've tried

`DELETE FROM PartOrder
WHERE PartOrder.pooid IN ( SELECT Orders.oid
FROM PartOrder INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.oid = PartOrder.pooid
WHERE Order.sdate < SYSDATE);`

When executing this I get an error that says missing expression in line 4.

Comment: It think your table name should be `Orders` instead of `Order` in the WHERE clause, `WHERE Order.sdate < SYSDATE);`

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed that

Comment: you can also use short alias name so you don't need to type in the whole table name